Bayesian updating with correlated signals
I would like to ask a broad question about Bayesian updating with correlated signals. Specifically, in my context I have an agent asking some questions. The signals are the answer. Since the question in time t is correlated to a certain extet to the ext onne, the signals are as well. I wanted to ask if there are notes on theoretical models about this instance. So the set up is the classical one on info economics, but we have that s_t=f(s_{t-1}).
Specifically, I build up the following scenario:

The key point with respect to classical information economics theory, is the fact that the signal in t depends in some way (let's say linearly to simplify the discourse) to the signal in t-1. The question is wheather I can consider this process an hidden markov model and how I can incorporate this in the updating of the belief.
Thank you

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
